# Need help in centering links below navbar-brand using Bootstrap 5

Tags: navbar, bootstrap-5

I am practicing how to create a navbar using Bootstrap 5 and can't get the links centered and below the navbar-brand.

I've attach an image of my current navbar.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXRTu.png)

My script:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg flex-column align-items-stretch" style="background-color: #FAF8F1; border:3px solid;">
     <div class="d-flex">
         <a class="navbar-brand mx-sm-auto mr-auto" href=""> Honeybee Babies </a>
         <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
             <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
         </button>
     </div>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100" id="navbarSupportedContent">
         <unli class="navbar-nav">
             <li class="nav-item rounded-pill" style="background-color:#C58940;">
                 <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FAF8F1" href="">Baby Essentials</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item rounded-pill" style="background-color:#C58940;">
                 <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FAF8F1" href="">Price Range</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-item rounded-pill" style="background-color:#C58940;">
                 <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FAF8F1" href="">Brands</a>
             </li>
         </unli>
         <form class="d-flex" role="search">
             <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
             <button class="btn" style="color:#C58940" type="submit">Search</button>
         </form>
     </div>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

I've tried using *justify-content-center* in

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help/advice would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `justify-content-center` to the `navbar-collapse`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg flex-column align-items-stretch" style="background-color: #FAF8F1; border:3px solid;">
  <div class="d-flex">
    <a class="navbar-brand mx-sm-auto mr-auto" href=""> Honeybee Babies </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 justify-content-center" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <unli class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item rounded-pill" style="background-color:#C58940;">
        <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FAF8F1" href="">Baby Essentials</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item rounded-pill" style="background-color:#C58940;">
        <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FAF8F1" href="">Price Range</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item rounded-pill" style="background-color:#C58940;">
        <a class="nav-link" style="color:#FAF8F1" href="">Brands</a>
      </li>
    </unli>
    <form class="d-flex" role="search">
      <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn" style="color:#C58940" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```